# Reducing overhead of indicatif ProgressBar in Rust

Tags: performance, rust, progress-bar

Let's say I have a following Rust code:

```rust
use indicatif::ProgressBar;

fn main() {
    let limit = 100_000_000;

    let pb = ProgressBar::new(limit);
    for i in 0..limit {
        pb.inc(1);
    }

    pb.finish();
}
```

It takes tens of seconds to execute this code.

Similarly, when I want to show a progress bar for a large number of loop with a small time taken for each loop, it seems indicatif updates the progress bar written on the terminal every loop and the overhead becomes significant.

Is there a way to reduce this overhead? For example, updating the progress bar every 50 milliseconds?

(I know I can do it from using `std::time::{Duration, Instant}` but I want to know simpler & readable solution if it exists.)

Comment: `indicatif` actually does implement its own mechanism for that (allowing 10 ticks per millisecond), but it's probably too fast for you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yup, I saw a significant decrease in time taken when I removed ProgressBar...

Comment: Did you compile your project with `--release`?

Comment: Yes. Still measurable overhead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`indicatif` implements its own filtering mechanism. But your problem is not the writes, even if we remove all of them, your code is still slow. Your problem is the filter itself.

To filter (10 ticks per millisecond) [it constructs an `Instant` on every call to `inc()`](https://docs.rs/indicatif/0.17.7/src/indicatif/progress_bar.rs.html#217). And constructing it is slow.

There are faster ways to get the current time than `Instant::now()`, but they're also more complicated. Probably, the best path forward is to call `inc()` only every N iterations.

Comment: I will go for calling `inc` on every N iterations for now as it was a fastest when I've tried. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Updating the progress bar every 50 ms without calling `Instant::now` in every iteration is possible, but quite a bit harder that you would like:

```rust
use indicatif::ProgressBar;
use std::{
    sync::atomic::{AtomicU64, Ordering::SeqCst},
    thread,
    time::Duration,
};

fn main() {
    let limit = 100_000_000;
    let current = AtomicU64::new(0);
    thread::scope(|s| {
        s.spawn(|| {
            let pb = ProgressBar::new(limit);
            loop {
                let current = current.load(SeqCst);
                match current {
                    u64::MAX => break,
                    current => pb.set_position(current),
                }
                thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(50));
            }
        });
        for i in 0..limit {
            current.store(i, SeqCst);
        }
        current.store(u64::MAX, SeqCst);
    });
}
```

Note that this is faster, but not orders of magnitude faster, than updating directly. At least on linux, `Instant::now` is pretty cheap. Atomic stores are cheaper, but not free.